# Is there a quicker way to enter formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In the firm I currently work in we have a very inefficient and time-consuming process for entering formulas. For example:

```
Y1=CHOOSE(B3,'[Flacflow balancesflacflow.xlsx]Data'!$A$77, '[Flacflow balancesflacflow.xlsx]Data'!$B$77, '[Flacflow balancesflacflow.xlsx]Data'!$C$77...)

Z1=CHOOSE(B3,'[Flacflow balancesflacflow.xlsx]Data'!$A$22, '[Flacflow balancesflacflow.xlsx]Data'!$B$22, '[Flacflow balancesflacflow.xlsx]Data'!$C$22...)
```

So, if `Z1=Revenue` and `Y1=Cost`, in this example we would have 3 days worth of figures. For one month, we need to enter this formula 30 times whilst changing the cell letter in each formula.

Is there a quicker and more efficient way to do this process?

Answer (score 1):

When a formula is copied down a column the cell references change to maintain row-to-row references (relative). *[screenshot: column C]*

When a dollar sign is added before a row and/or column reference, XL keeps it fixed to that reference (absolute).  *[screenshot: column B]*

Perhaps if a portion of your formula had the dollar signs removed and then copied the formula it would update as you desire. Either copy & paste the formula or grab the fill handle and drag.

[image: Excel fill handle]

[image: Relative & absolute formulas]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive I fully understand what you are trying to do but if it is just selecting a value from a different table then you might have more luck with the **index** function which you can input a proper array to

```
Y1=index('[Flacflow balancesflacflow.xlsx]Data'!$A77:$C77,B3)
```

This assumes that B has a value like 2 (which would mean you want the second cell in the range).

If you want anything more specific you need to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just 30 times, you might want to use the easiest way of linking cell data.

Make it so that you have both the source and destination open in the same Excel. Then select the cell you want to enter the formula. Type an = and without typing anything else, just click on the cell you want to link to, and press enter.